# Show rows on top of each other if and only if posted on same day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like

```
+---------------------+-------+
| date_in             | title |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | foo2  |
| 2018-01-02 00:00:00 | bar   |
| 2018-01-03 00:00:00 | man   |
| 2018-01-04 01:00:00 | foo2  |
| 2018-01-04 02:00:00 | foo   |
| 2018-01-04 03:00:00 | foo1  |
| 2018-01-04 04:00:00 | foo2  |
| 2018-01-05 00:00:00 | test  |
+---------------------+-------+
```

My desired result is

```
+---------------------+-------+
| date_in             | title |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-01-05 00:00:00 | test  |
| 2018-01-04 04:00:00 | foo2  | -- see this
| 2018-01-04 01:00:00 | foo2  | -- see this
| 2018-01-04 03:00:00 | foo1  |
| 2018-01-04 02:00:00 | foo   |
| 2018-01-03 00:00:00 | man   |
| 2018-01-02 00:00:00 | bar   |
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | foo2  |
+---------------------+-------+
```

I have tried below query and other several queries but it doesn't work

```
SELECT
    detail.* 
FROM
    test detail
    JOIN ( SELECT min( date_in ) firstdate, title FROM test GROUP BY title ) firstdate ON detail.title = firstdate.title 
ORDER BY
    firstdate.firstdate,
    detail.title,
    detail.date_in
```

but this query shows rows with same titles on top o each other regardless of date

***I want rows to show on top of each other only if they are on same day***

Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/039aa/6 SQLFiddle with schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems you need  order by date(date_in)  and title  desc

```
 SELECT
    detail.* 
 FROM test detail
 ORDER BY
    date(detail.date_in),
    detail.title desc,
    detail.date_in
```

Comment: @Umair if my answer  is right and is the faster .. should correct mark and rate it properly

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually want to order the titles by the latest time on each date.  In MySQL 8+, you can do:

```
 SELECT d.* 
 FROM test d
 ORDER BY date(d.date_in),
          MAX(d.date_in) OVER (PARTITION BY date(d.date_in), d.title),
          d.title desc,
          d.date_in ;
```

In earlier versions, you can use a subquery.  Here is one method:

```
 SELECT d.* 
 FROM test d
 ORDER BY date(d.date_in),
          (SELECT MAX(d2.date_in) FROM test d2 WHERE d2.title = d.title AND DATE(d2.date_in) = DATE(d.date_in)),
          d.title desc,
          d.date_in;
```

Or, you can use an explicit `JOIN`:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM test d JOIN
     (SELECT d2.title, DATE(d2.date_in) as date, MAX(d2.date_in) as max_date_in
      FROM test d2
      GROUP BY d2.title, DATE(d2.date_in) 
     ) d2
     ON d2.title = d.title AND d2.date = DATE(d.date_in)
ORDER BY date(d.date_in),
         d2.max_date_in,
         d.title desc,
         d.date_in
```

Comment: I have MySQL 5.6

Comment: Whose answer is better in terms of performance? @scaisEdge or yours?

Comment: your subquery (because I have MySQL5.6) solution takes forever, whereas  @scaisEdge solution takes less than a second

Comment: @Umair . . . The issue is not which runs faster but which does what you want.  The answers implement different logic.

Comment: so far @scaisEdge answer gives correct results, do you think scaisEdge answer can fail or give incorrect results? thanks for your time :)

Comment: @umair . . . If you rename "foo1" to "foo5" in your sample data, does it still do what you want?

Comment: I tried that with scaisedge query and it produces correct results

Comment: @Umair . . . If that is the answer you want, then accept it.  This does something different -- it returns the titles based on the most recent time on each date, rather than just alphabetically.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    detail.* 
FROM
    test detail
    JOIN ( SELECT min( date_in ) firstdate, title FROM test GROUP BY title ) firstdate ON detail.title = firstdate.title 
ORDER BY
    DATE(detail.date_in),
    detail.title;
```

Removed `firstdate.firstdate` and edit `DATE(detail.date_in)` from `ORDER BY`.

Comment: There's no point selecting a column in a subquery if you do nothing with it in the super query.

Comment: I just copy paste OP's original query and change some @Strawberry . It might be coming from another big query that the OP's had specifically took out to ask this question. But yeah, you're correct. I didn't even look at the sub-query whether it's being used or not.

Comment: WAIT! it was being used for the ordering part.. which I removed here